Salesforce Managed 2GP Setup for NamedCredentials with External Credentials
Objective: Create Salesforce Apex package to be distributed, as an integration with a third party service
Development Details: API v61 (Summer 24), SF CLI
Development Steps: Following the workflow Workflow for Second-Generation Managed Packages
Summarizing the steps:

Create DevHub Org
Create named credentials in DevHub Org: dev_named and dev_external
Create another DevHub Org for namespace(Namespace Org): ns
Link Dev Hub Org with Namespace Org
Salesforce CLI login to devhub org (all steps in sf cli use devhub org)
Salesforce CLI create project
Salesforce CLI create package
Add metadata to package: 'callout:dev_named'
Package named credential: sf project retrieve -m NamedCredential --target-org devhuborg
Salesforce CLI create package version

Step 10 Throws error:
Error (MultipleErrorsError): Multiple errors occurred:
(1) dev_named: The ns__dev_external External Credential doesn't exist.

Noticing the associated namespace I created the same pair of credentials(named, external) in namespace account
Rerun package version creation command: No errors
Go to devhub org to test the callout in dev console: with 'callout:dev_named'
System.CalloutException: The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential "dev_named" might not exist.

The three conceptual steps involved in the flow for named credentials are

Setup
Packaging: Includes package version creation
Usage

What am I missing and what step needs correction, either the setup, the packaging or the usage?

The thing that was missing was to also package external credentials, once I was able to get that, package creation went smoothly
sf project retrieve -m ExternalCredential --target-org devhuborg
